# Java String to Long Conversion

Tags: java

Simple problem i know but I cannot see what is wrong. I have the following code:

```
String dxorderId = request.getParameter("orderid");
    long orderid = Long.parseLong((dxorderId));
```

It is inside a servlet which is called from a PL/SQL procedure. The value of dxorderid is retrieved from a parameter in the URL of the page called. Therefore it seems to be treated as a string. So I must convert the string into a long. However, when I use the code above, I get the following error:

```
14-Nov-2013 13:07:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.zf.proceed.service.servlets.ViewOrderServlet] in context with path [/webapp] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:372)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:461)
at com.zf.proceed.service.servlets.ViewOrderServlet.doRequest(ViewOrderServlet.java:28)
at com.zf.proceed.service.servlets.ProceedBaseServlet.doRequest(ProceedBaseServlet.java:106)
at com.zf.proceed.service.servlets.ProceedBaseServlet.doGet(ProceedBaseServlet.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I know it means that it cant be parsed but I dont Know why it cant. the value being input is 1454.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` . `dxorderId` is null.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` value is null and null cann't be parsed to long.

Comment: i think you are not getting parameter value through request.getParameter.Try print the dxorderId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the value is not `1454`. The value is `null`, as evidenced by this line:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

You need to check your parameter name, and make sure you've got it right, including case and invisible characters.

Comment: Those damned capital letters!!!! The vain of my life. I knew it would be something simple. Thanks Chris. I will accept your answer when it lets me!!

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

If String `dxorderId`  is null then it will throw NumberFormatException

**Solution**

Check `dxorderId` is not `null` and not `empty string`

```
if(dxorderId != null && !dxorderId.equals(""))
{
  long orderid = Long.parseLong((dxorderId));
}
```

From [oracle docs NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

```
public class NumberFormatException
       extends IllegalArgumentException
```

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

Use [createLong](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#createLong%28java.lang.String%29) or [toLong](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong%28java.lang.String%29) method from Apache's NumberUtils.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the exception closely : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

the above statement indicates that value for `dxorderId` is null. Problem is with this line:

```
String dxorderId = request.getParameter("orderid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a `NumberFormatException` means that the given Data can not be converted to a `Long` because it does not represent a `Long`-Value, so the problem lies at the source of the String, not in the Java Long-Parser.

In your specific case the Parser states that the given value was `null`, so your `request.getParameter("orderid");` return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

From the exception information, we can learn that **dxorderid** is **null**  which causes `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Before parsing data, you need to check whether the value  to  be parsed is  **null** or  **empty** first  .

Answer (score 0):

error is due to this line.

```
String dxorderId = request.getParameter("orderid");
```

Check whether parameter name "orderid" is correct or not or ensure that its value is not null